# Can I reproduce geographical distance by connecting VPN server?

Tags: server, vpn, ping

Let's say a gaming server is only hosted in Japan.

UserA lives in Japan.  To reach a gaming server(Japan), it takes 10ms.

UserB lives in Brazil. To reach a gaming server(Japan), it takes 50ms.

(Distance from Japan to Brazil 17,360 km)

If userA uses a VPN that is hosted in Brazil and accesses a gaming server(Japan), am I technically accessing from Brazil, and ping time would be similar to 50ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would add more bottleneck.

A network request using a VPN looks like this:

```
Request -> VPN server routes the request -> Server -> VPN -> sends it back -> Response
```

That's why VPN's are not something for speed.

Comment: There would be more network requests than purely accessing from Brazil.
It wouldn't be similar because of the bottleneck, right?

access from Brazil is faster than  connecting VPN(Brazil) server from Japan

Comment: Yep, that's right